# Problema al tratar de sumar dígitos de un array de objetos para que me salgan solo los objetos cuya suma sea igual a un numero de entrada

Tags: javascript, array, json, angular, typescript

he traido la informacion de una API cuyo json me trae un array con objetos de jugadores y cada jugador tiene una altura, entonces estoy tratando de sumar la altura de cada jugador para que solo me aparezcan los jugadores cuya suma sea igual a lo que digite el usuario como entrada. Por ejemplo si el usuario digita 150, me tiene que salir todos los jugadores cuya suma de 150. Creo tener el codigo bien pero el operador +=, no entiendo por que me presenta un error y me dice: `que se esperaba ","`. Este es el código compañeros.

```
private getAllPlayers(){
    return this.http.get<Jugadores[]>('https://mach-eight.uc.r.appspot.com')
    .pipe(
      map(item => item.values)
    )
    .subscribe( (data: any) => {
      this.datos= data;

      //En este array quiero almacenar los objetos cuya altura sumen 140
      let newJugadores:Jugadores[]=[];

      //Filtramos y almacenamos los objetos cuya altura son menores a 70 (item.h_in es la altura)
      const Jugadores= this.datos.filter(item=> parseInt(item.h_in) <= 100);

      //Recorremos posicion por posicion los objetos de ese array
      for(let i=0; i < Jugadores.length; i++){

        //Trato de ir sumando la altura de cada objeto, pero el operador += me da error
        let suma += parseInt(Jugadores[i].h_in);
        //Si la suma igual a 140
        if(suma === 140){

          //Pujamos esos objetos al array
          newJugadores.push(Jugadores[i]);
        }
      }
      console.log(newJugadores);
    });
  }
```

Está es la captura del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero aclarar que la propiedad de la altura del jugador osea "h_in" viene en string y por eso lo estoy parseando como entero para poder hacer la suma.

Si alguno me pudiera ayudar, se los agradecería de ante mano compañeros, no se si mi código esta bien o en que pudiera estar fallando.

**Edit:** Noto que se estan agragando todos los jugadores cuyo filtro, filtraba que tuvieran una altura menor a 100, más no los jugadores cuya suma de las alturas sea 140. Observa que esos 435 serían los jugadores con una altura menores a 100 y no solo los jugadores cuya suma debe ser 140:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al `console.log(newJugadores);` le agregue el texto de concatenacion:         `console.log("Objeto jugadores: "+ newJugadores);`

Comment: ¿Por que declaras suma en cada ciclo? Suma debería estar inicializada a cero fuera del ciclo. Por otro lado, no entiendo lo que quieres hacer bien ¿Todos los jugadores cuya suma sea 150? O sea, ¿empezar a sumar gente random ahí hasta llegar a 150?

Comment: Con dos personas que sumes ya llegas a 150 teniendo en cuenta esos números. Explica bien lo que quieres porque no hace sentido. Ahora mismo solo pondrás una sola persona en el arreglo de newJugadores si llegas ("por casualidad divina") a sumar 140, pero bien puedes nunca llegar a 140 y saltar a 180 por ejemplo con dos personas que midan 90. Por otro lado, los comentarios y el código andan desfasados totalmente, filtras por 100 y dices en comentarios que por 70. Dices que 150 y tienes 140.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto además debe contribuir a depurar tu código:
En el parseo a int que intentas agregar, veo dos veces el mismo valor:

let suma += **parseInt(Jugadores[i].h_in** + **Jugadores[i].h_in**);

Revisa, eso sería una concatenación de la misma string, si esa construcción estuviera completa.

***Debe ser algo similar a:***:

```
let suma += parseInt(Jugadores[i].h_in);
```

**Finalmente, debes cambiar esto:**

```
let suma = 0; // antes del for
```

y la instrucción queda:

```
suma += parseInt(Jugadores[i].h_in);
```

**Ya que: let declara variables y opcionalmente permite asignarles un valor**
El operador += no es aceptable en una declaración let. Solo puedes usar =

Comment: Es cierto brother, habia una concatenacion en el parseo pero ya lo reduje como lo propusiste y me sigue dando el mismo error en esa linea de codigo. En cuanto al item, me tira error si lo agrego, creo que no es necesario porque ese item solo pertenece al filter. Pero volviendo a al tema del operador no entiendo el error si se supone que estoy aculando enteros al hacer ese casting

Comment: Funciono!, inicializar el let antes del for me quito el error DEVX75, muchas gracias de verdad. Ahora esta pasando que el push no me esta añadiendo los objetos de los jugadores cuya altura sumada da 140. El console.log(newJugadores) no me esta imprimiendo nada del array como si el push no le estuviera añadiendo nada. Sabes que podría ser?

Comment: Yo mejoraría dos cosas, cambiar ese nombre del const y subsiguientes. También esto: if(suma === 140)  debe ser simplemente if(suma == 140) ya que === es otra cosa, implica que el tipo y el valor son iguales e idénticos

Comment: Ya habia cambiado el nombre de const y los subsiguientes de Jugadores a Players y también modifique el if(suma == 140) pero sigo sin ver el array con los objetos en consola. Me doy cuenta en consola que se agrega un contador con el numero de objetos que se agregaron pero no imprime un array para poder desplegar y mirar el contenido. Voy a editar mi post y subire una captura de lo que me sale en consola para que lo puedas ver brother

Comment: @Hugo, lee mi comentario. Imagina el primer jugador tiene altura 90. Suma vale 90 porque 0 + 90 = 90. Ahora el segundo jugador mide 80. Ahora suma es 170. Como ves, nunca pasó por 140, por tanto, nunca va a entrar al condicional ni va a agregar nada en el arreglo. Tu lógica carece de sentido. Explica por favor mejor lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Ok, revisa datos también para ver si de casualidad DIVINA como dice @JaimeMenéndez, tienes algunos que sumen ese valor que pruebas. Si es un array de objetos dificlmente los veras con un console.log, prueba a hacer un for e itera en los valores a listar en consola

Comment: Lo que dice Jaime podría ser cierto, pero me acabo de asegurar y filtre solo los que tengan una altura de 70 los cuales son solo 3 (esos son los 3 que están en la API), dos tienen altura 70 y uno tiene de altura 69, entonces con esos dos de altura 70 debería sumarme 140 verdad? y al imprimir el array newJugadores me esta almacenando esos 3 jugadores y no solo los dos que suman 140, pero entonces el array que me imprime en consola no me imprime como un array osea no lo puedo desplegar para ver los datos. Si se fijan en el edit que hice donde subi una captura ya no son 435 sino 3 notificaciones

Comment: No, no es así, tienes una suma CONTINUA sobre todos los jugadores, por eso si los n  primeros no te dan el valor buscado de manera exacta,  jamás se agregarán al resultado. Además debes ser específico cuantos jugadores son validos que puedan sumarse, pueden ser 3, 4, 5? -> Además tu código está diseñado para guardar solo el jugador con el que completas la suma exacta, y no todos los jugadores que participan de esa suma

Comment: ¿Podría ser cierto? XD. Primero: Estás guardando UN SOLO OBJETO solo cuando la suma sea EXACTAMENTE 140. O sea que si primero aparece el de 70, como la suma es 70 no lo guarda. Próximo ciclo, suponiendo que el segundo igual mide 70, ahí la suma es 140, entra al ciclo, y guarda el de 70.  Ahora imagina que el segundo en lugar de ser 70 es 69, pues ya nunca va a entrar. No sé cómo esperas tener más de un jugador. La pregunta es la que está mal formulada de raíz. En todo caso deberías preguntar algo cómo, "los pares de jugadores que sumen 140" o algo así.

Comment: El texto no me alcanzo para corregir, lo ultimo que hice fue filtrar los jugadores con una altura menores o igual a 70 y entre todos solo hay 3, dos de 70 y uno de 69

Comment: Si están [69,70,70] o [70,69,70] nunca va a funcionarte. Solo funcionará imprimiendote UN SOLO JUGADOR en la posición [70,70,69]

Comment: Exactamente como dice @JaimeMenéndez, es decir los n primeros de suerte te dan la suma exacta y solo asi funciona, y te agrega solo ese último jugador.

Esa premisa del problema puede tener resultados más complejos como esta estructura teórica JSON:

    [
        { "resultado": "1", [{<objeto player1>},{<objeto player2>}]},
        { "resultado": "2",  [{<objeto player3>},{<objeto player5>},{<objeto player8>}]}
    ]

Comment: Los leo muchachos y creo que tiene mucha logica lo que dicen. Acá ando como loco mirando como solucionarlo, porque es que necesito que de todos los jugadores que hay en la API, según el numero que el usuario digite me deben aparecer solo los jugadores cuya la suma de las alturas da ese numero de entrada por parte del usuario, o sea pueden haber 15, 4, , etc.. de jugadores que cumplen con ese requisito y solo a ellos debo mostrar. Entonces con decirles que en el if, el 140 es de prueba porque allí debería ir una variable que guarde un input.

Comment: Y el filtrado también porque no debo filtrar los jugadores con una altura menores de 70 o 100 sino que debo filtrar las alturas de todos los jugadores. Entonces hasta aquí ando como perdido, no se que me aconsejan ustedes, debo reformular el codigo? o solo modificar alguna parte de él? o ustedes tienen alguna idea de cual sería la solución?

Comment: Sugiero abras otra pregunta, con respecto  a la lógica JS para lograr el resultado, de manera bien específica. Tu pregunta sobre el error de sintaxis,  fue resuelta, esta ya es otra @Hugo

Comment: @Hugo yo te aconsejo pensar un poquito qué es lo que quieres. La consigna "los jugadores que sumen 140"  me parece vaga y sin sentido. Si dijeras algo como "los pares de jugadores que suman 140" podrías hacer algo cómo esto https://playcode.io/886090. Nota que el resultado es un array de pares donde cada par suma 140. Piensa el problema de manera lógica, porque creo que ni tu mismo sabes lo que quieres. El filtrado si lo estás haciendo correcto.

Comment: @DEVX75 tiene razón. El error que planteabas en esta pregunta de sintaxis fue resuelto. Acepta la respuesta de DEVX75 y abre otra pregunta cuando tengas una idea más clara de tus requerimientos, y no digo de código, me refiero a conceptualmente.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez Le di mucha cabeza anoche que no pude dormir y hoy después de todo me di cuenta que el concepto que estaba buscando era el de "hallar los pares de jugadores que suman x numero", entonces mirando el código que me enviaste de playcode.io, es el que me resuelve el problema. Solo me gustaria preguntarte dos dudas del código que no entiendo. Porque usaste 2 ciclos for? y porque colocaste en el parseint como base 10?